# How to load image in ImageView dynamically in Java FX

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml, image-viewer

I'm working with FXML and have two different Scene on a single Stage. btnStart is on scene1, and imgBtn is on scene2. When I click btnStart it sets scene2 to stage and loads an image to imageView (this is throwing NullPointerException). But when I click imgBtn on scene2 it is loading image.

My question is how to load image dynamically when I switch to scene2 ?

```
@FXML private Button imgBtn;
@FXML private Button btnStart;
@FXML public ImageView imageView;

@FXML
public void imgBtnClicked()throws Exception{      
    imageView.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream("src/Assets/CardAssets/png-v2/3C.png")));
}


@FXML
public void btnStartClicked()throws Exception{
    SetScene2();
    imageView.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream("src/Assets/CardAssets/png-v2/3C.png")));

}  

public void SetScene2()throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile2.fxml));
    String css=getClass().getResource("myStyle.css").toExternalForm();
    Scene scene;
    try{
        scene=new Scene(root,root.getScene().getWidth(),root.getScene().getHeight());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        scene=new Scene(root,stage.getWidth(),stage.getHeight());
    }
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    stage.setScene(scene);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not exactly very clear, so I'm going to make some guesses here. The most likely problem is that you have confused which `Node`s are on which scene which is on which controller.

The correct structure for this is that you have two sets of each of the following items:

1. FXML file
2. Controller class
3. `Scene` object.

This is how it should be done:

```
public class ControllerA {
    @FXML private Button btnStart;

    @FXML
    public void btnStartClicked()throws Exception{
        setScene2();
    }  

    public void setScene2()throws Exception {
        // You may need to set the controller to an instance of ControllerB,
        // depending whether you have done so on the FXML.
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile2.fxml));

        String css=getClass().getResource("myStyle.css").toExternalForm();
        Scene scene;
        try{
            scene=new Scene(root,root.getScene().getWidth(),root.getScene().getHeight());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            scene=new Scene(root,stage.getWidth(),stage.getHeight());
        }
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

}

public class ControllerB {
    @FXML private ImageView imageView;
    @FXML private Button imgBtn;

    @FXML public void initialize() {
        imageView.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream("src/Assets/CardAssets/png-v2/3C.png")));
    }

    @FXML
    public void imgBtnClicked()throws Exception{      
        imageView.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream("src/Assets/CardAssets/png-v2/3C.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I set one single controller for both FXML 's. I am new to this type of programming, I have one array in that controller class containing some cards whose image is to be loaded to scene2's imageView. And from scene1 I'm generating the content of the array.

Comment: @HemanKundu "I set one single controller for both FXMLs". No, that's not true - the `FXMLLoader` creates a new controller whenever you call `load()`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but in both FXML files, I have  set     fx:controller="HeartsApp" . So that I can access an array from both the scenes as mentioned. Is there any alternative way to doing it?

Comment: @James_D Can you please help?

Comment: @HemanKundu Like I said, each FXML should have its own controller class. Mixing everything together just isn't the correct way to do it.